# Remove nomodeset from grub but it's not there

Tags: 20.04, grub2, nomodeset

I want to remove `nomodeset` but it's not in my `/etc/default/grub` config.

Ubuntu 20.04

This is my grub config:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="consoleblank=0 systemd.show_status=true elevator=noop console=tty1 console=ttyS0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

I've also looked in `/etc/grub.d` and did some grepping.:

```
me@system:/etc/grub.d$ grep nomodeset ./*
./10_linux:    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY nomodeset"
./10_linux_zfs:        GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY="${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_RECOVERY} nomodeset"
```

Should I remove it here? Looks like it's only for recovery.

My dmesg states this:

```
[    0.000000] kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.13.0-39-generic root=UUID=xxxxx ro nomodeset consoleblank=0
```

Answer (score 0):

After running `update-grub` I saw it was sourcing the next files:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/hetzner.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
```

The line I was looking for was in the second file.